# How to remove specific common keys in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
res = [
    {'termA':'A1', 'termB':'B1', 'termC':'C1'},
    {'termA':'A2', 'termB':'B2', 'termC':'C2'},
    {'termA':'A3', 'termB':'B3', 'termC':'C3'}
]
```

Each dictionary has the same keys but different values for the corresponding keys (like a matrix). I am trying to find the fastest way to remove (or to extract) certain keys (say, `termA` and `termB`) from all dictionaries in the list.

My first thought was a for loop. Suppose from `res` only `termC` is to be kept:

```
new = [] 
for i in res: 
    new.append({'termC':i['termC']})
```

It works as expected:

```
new = [{'termC':'C1'},{'termC':'C2'},{'termC':'C3'}]
```

but it is very slow in the actual scale. List comprehension is slow as well. Is there any improvement I can make on the existing code, or is there a better way to deal with this?

---

In addition, I tried converting the list to dataframe. It is also time-consuming.

Comment: Might as well use `pandas` if you have a datastructure like this.

Comment: Thought of that also, it turned out using pd.DataFrame is just as time-consuming.

Comment: Odd, I would've expected it to be faster

Comment: Maybe an X-Y-problem. Why can't you use the dicts as is? Why are the additional keys bothering you in the first place?

Comment: For clarity, can you post your Python version, and timings of the list comprehension vs. a `for` loop, using `%timeit`? https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit

Comment: How are the numbers in the real data. How many keys do you want to drop, how many do  you want to retain?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your program has to be O(n), `n = len(res)`.

If the speed of your program is a problem, maybe you should think about another way to do what you want.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use more built in functions (as opposed to Python structured code) but I doubt you'll get much faster than what you already have:

```
res = [{'termA':'A1', 'termB':'B1', 'termC':'C1'},
       {'termA':'A2', 'termB':'B2', 'termC':'C2'},
       {'termA':'A3', 'termB':'B3', 'termC':'C3'}]

keys  = ['termC'] # keys in a list in case you want more than one at a time

*new, = map(lambda d:dict(zip(keys,map(d.get,keys))),res)

print(new)
[{'termC': 'C1'}, {'termC': 'C2'}, {'termC': 'C3'}]
```

or a more concise version for a single key:

```
key   = 'termC'
*new, = map(lambda d:{key:d[key]},res)

print(new)
[{'termC': 'C1'}, {'termC': 'C2'}, {'termC': 'C3'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with pandas fairly easily:

```py
import pandas as pd

res = [
    {"termA": "A1", "termB": "B1", "termC": "C1"},
    {"termA": "A2", "termB": "B2", "termC": "C2"},
    {"termA": "A3", "termB": "B3", "termC": "C3"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(res)

print(df["termC"].to_list())
```

Output:

```
['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
```

Or if you don't want to use pandas:

```py
new = [{k: v for k, v in x.items() if k == "termC"} for x in res]
print(new)
```

Output:

```
[{'termC': 'C1'}, {'termC': 'C2'}, {'termC': 'C3'}]
```

What is the scale of your data? Any method will be fast with the small sample.

Comment: I am downvoting this because the methods you proposed, the OP already discarded as viable options